# How to dynamically intercept methods in a jar without altering code?

Tags: java, methods, jar, runtime

I have a jar file containing multiple .class files. Each .class file has several methods in it. Now, while the jar is executing, i.e. during runtime, I want to intercept the methods with an external user defined method. That is, I want to run an external method before or after each method call in my jar classes.

I have looked into Spring-AOP, but it says I need to declare the classes in the Spring context and hence the classes will be called with their methods in the sequence in which it is written in the Spring context.

But I want the execution flow to be that of the original jar webapp.

Can you share with me anything which can be used to achieve what I explained above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JVM instrumentation API, it allows you to modify classes being loaded using some library like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/. See example here https://web.archive.org/web/20181012004753/http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html

Comment: But this API modifies classes during load time and not runtime, am I correct? I need to inject external code during runtime. Is that possible?

Comment: You inject your code during class loading but it will work during runtime

Comment: But I want to inject during runtime only :(. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: But loading a class happens during runtime, when you first use the class. I think instrumentation is what you are looking for

Comment: Ok! Then tell me one thing. During load time I am injecting some external code to my original class. Now, do I need to create a new jar with the modified code and then run it? Or, it works in a way such that code is injected during loadtime and it is directly run after that, creating no new jar.

Comment: No new jar. Only classes being loaded are fixed and fixed only in memory. Besides you can select which classes and which method to instrument and which leave unchanged

Comment: Ok! That is great! This will work for me just fine!!